# How to determine the origin of a LocalJumpError?

Tags: ruby, proxy, decorator

How can I determine easily and programmatically whether a `LocalJumpError` arose from the caller's immediate failure to supply a needed block to a method, or from deeper within that method and others it invokes?

By "easily," I mean I'd like to avoid string inspection/regexen on `$!.backtrace`.  A solution applicable to 1.8 and 1.9 is also preferred.

**Motivation:**  When I botch a method call in ruby, it's usually because I mistyped the method (`NoMethodError`), got the number of arguments wrong (`ArgumentError`) or neglected to pass a necessary block (`LocalJumpError`).

For a proxying or decorating wrapper object in ruby, I'd like to discriminate these *caller or API errors* from the *implementor or environment errors* that can raise the same classes of error.  For example:

```
...
def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
  @wrapped.__send__(sym, *args, &block)
rescue NoMethodError
  raise MyApp::BadInvocation, "duh - no such method" unless @wrapped.respond_to?(sym)
  raise
rescue ArgumentError
  raise MyApp::BadInvocation, "duh - wrong arg count" \
    unless _args_fit_arity?(@wrapped.method(sym), args)
  raise
rescue LocalJumpError
  # XXX - what is the test?
  raise
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out whether the LocalJumpError was caused by the user forgetting to pass a block, you need to know two things: Whether the user supplied a block and whether the method needs a block. The first is easy: just check whether blk is nil. The second however is impossible (in plain ruby at least).

So I guess parsing the stack trace is your best bet.

Comment: +1  It had not occurred to me to check whether a block was actually supplied.  (Still don't like parsing the backtrace *per se*, however.)

Comment: @sepp2k, I think I found a better bet ... will post in a moment.

Comment: @sepp2k, I think I win for strict accuracy, but you win for simplicity, which is a better criterion here. :)

Answer (score 0):

One can examine the *relative depth of the `backtrace`* to make a best effort discriminate caller error from a subsequent error deeper in the call stack:

```
def lje_depth_from_send
  Class.new { def lje; yield end }.new.__send__ :lje
rescue LocalJumpError
  return $!.backtrace.size - caller(0).size
end

def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
  ...
rescue LocalJumpError
  if !block_given? and ($!.backtrace.size - caller(0).size) == lje_depth_from_send
    raise MyApp::BadInvocation, "duh - you forgot to supply a block"
  end
  raise
end
```

Interestingly, this relative depth calculation changes from MRI 1.8 to MRI 1.9 -- the former tracks **send**, the latter seems to silently omit it (ala perl's `goto &sub`, perhaps?), for example.  (Under 1.9, the LJE backtrace is *shallower* than the `caller(0)` stack, because 1.9 explicitly counts the `rescue` block as a discrete stack frame).

Now, this might not work under non-MRI, but I doubt parsing of the call stack would be portable from one implementation to another, either.